# What is an easy way to see how often recently added pages are viewed in google analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

Google Analytics makes it very easy to see the number of views of the most-viewed pages, but I cannot figure out how to see the number of views a particular page has received, or the number of views of recently added pages (e.g. blog posts).  Is it possible to sort the pageviews list by date the page was added?

Can this be done without having to externally create a list of recent pages and use the analytics API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This task would be better suited to a review of your webserver's logs (or an analytics package which analyzes your logs), however, if Google Analytics is your only option, the most straightforward way of accomplishing this task would be to create a [custom variable](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables) which stores the product of subtracting the post's [POSIX timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) for the date the article was published from the timestamp for the date the article was viewed.

Once you are tracking the seconds in timestamp difference, you can create [advanced segments](http://www.google.com/analytics/features/advanced-segments.html) in Google Analytics to display views for articles which were published in the last day (difference <= 86400), week (604800), year (~31536000), etc.